# c regex not finding string

Tags: c, regex

I'm trying to create a collection of regexes in C, with no much success.

Currently I'm trying to find `include` statements with the following regex:

```
(#include <.+>)|(#include \".+\")
```

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>

char *regex_str = "(#include <.+>)|(#include \".+\")";
char *str = "#include <stdio.h>";

regex_t regex;
int reti;

int main() {
    /* Compile Regex */
    reti = regcomp(&regex, regex_str, 0);

    if (reti) {
        printf("Could not compile regex.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Exec Regex */
    reti = regexec(&regex, str, 0, NULL, 0);

    if (!reti) {
        printf("Match\n");
    } else if (reti == REG_NOMATCH) {
        printf("No Match\n");
    } else {
        regerror(reti, &regex, str, sizeof(str));
        printf("Regex match failed: %s\n", str);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Free compiled regular expression if you want to use the regex_t again */
    regfree(&regex);

    return 0;
}
```

The result I get is: `No Match`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually, it's working: https://regex101.com/r/eN4nP6/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to escape your match group:

```
char *regex_str = "\\(#include [\"<].*[\">]\\)";
```

Which could likely be rolled into one pattern.

Comment: So which character I was supposed to escape?

Comment: The `(` group `)`, which is defined by parentheses needs escaping eg. `\\( ... \\)`